# How to Create ManaedExecutorService from Weblogic 10.3.6 console?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, weblogic-10.x

I'm trying to create Container Managed Object on Weblogic 10.3.6 , but when I go to the weblogic console I can't find the option of

> Environment > Concurrent Templates

on the the left panel. I wanted to use `ManagedExecutorService`.

Can anyone please help me in this regard? Why I am not able to see Concurrent Templates option on Weblogic 10.3.6? Does it not support CMO objects?

Comment: Please let me know if anybody has any kind of idea related to above question. I'm really stuck with this issue.